# Computing radius of convergence for series without coefficients explicitly defined

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the series

$$
1 - x^2 + x^4 - x^6 + \cdots = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x-3)^n.
$$

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence for this series. However, I'm having trouble coming up with a formula for the coefficients $a_n$ since the series is not centered at $x=0$.

At first glance, I thought that $a_n = 0$ for odd $n$ and that it alternated between $1$ and $-1$ for even $n$. However, computing the first several terms, I see that this is not the case.

Comment: how does that help me?

Comment: If what you want is to find the radius of convergence, you dont need to know the $a_n$. The LHS is equal to:

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1-(-x^2)}$$
Wich converges for $\vert -x^2 \vert < 1$ i.e. for $\vert x \vert < 1$

Comment: Hmm...I'm just a bit confused because the answer my instructor gave us for this question was $1/10$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $x=3+z$, then the LHS is $$\frac1{1+x^2}=\frac1{1+(z+3)^2}=\frac1{(z+3+i)(z+3-i)}=\frac{i/2}{z+3+i}-\frac{i/2}{z+3-i}.$$ One can deduce the series expansion in powers of $z$ but, if only the radius of convergence is concerned, the coefficients $(a_n)$ of the expansion are not needed: note simply that the disk of convergence is defined by the inequality $$|z|\lt\min\{|-3-i|,|-3+i|\}=\sqrt{10},$$ thus, the radius of convergence of the RHS is $R=\sqrt{10}$.